# Calculate sum of array cells within a given radius

Tags: r

This questions comes after a calculation in GIS (ArcMap 10.1) takes over a month to calculate (and didn't finish yet). Now I am trying to find a faster solution in R.

I have a matrix of ~30,000 x 80,000 cells, where each cell represents a 5x5 meters square. I need to calculate the sum of values in cells that fall within a given radius (3000 meters) from each cell. 
For the cells on the edge of the matrix I assume a value of 0 outside the matrix.

The question is how to define the cells that fall within the radius.
There must be a library that has this functionality, but I couldn't find any.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not surprised it's taking some time. You have 2.4 billion cells. For ***each*** of your 2.4 billion cells, you have to work out which of the other cells falls within 3000m then sum the values. Why don't you either... get it working at a spatial resolution of 100m cells, thus reducing your processing overhead by `(100/5)^2 = 400` times as a first approximation so you know it works. If you are keen on using `r` then look at `raster::focal` and `raster::focalWeight`, but to do this for every cell is still going to take *aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaages*

Comment: The distance calc isnt that tricky assuming a regular grid in your coordinate system - you can actually just pre-calculate a set of x-y offsets of the cells. But if my maths is right a radius of 3000m on 5m cells means a radius of 600 cells, so that's 1130973 cells you are summing over. For each of your 2.4 billion cells. There may be an approach where you just consider the delta between adjacent cells and add/sub the values in the change of the window...

Comment: Of course this is also fairly embarrassingly parallel so you could spin-up a cluster of 1000 Amazon instances and then you might get it done in your lifetime.

Comment: So the obvious response is: why do you need such astonishingly fine resolution both in your source grid and in your results grid?  Unless you've got spectacularly large values in the high-spatial-frequency region (FFT of your data), you'll probably get 99% accuracy by block-summing your array to, say 300x800 pixels and operating on that.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. First a little clarification: my raster consists of the population density over an entire country. So the raster is not a rectangle full of data but consists of many cell with NoData or 0 value (e.g. over the sea or across the border). So in fact I want to run the calculation only on cells with data, which leaves about half of the cells in the rectangle of 30,00 x 80,000. I was thinking to extract cells with data with !is.na and iterate on them.

Comment: You seriously have population density data down to 5x5m hatches? I would find that pointless in rural areas, and, as I suggested before, even in Manhattan the **variation** from one grid to the next is almost certainly microscopic.   Collapse your matrix!

Answer (score 2):

A quick method you can test, would be to use `extract` and set `buffer` to 3000m and then use `sum` in the `fun` argument. You can sequentially extract each cell number in your raster. But I still think this will take an inordinate amount of time. Let's assume your raster is called `r`....

```
#  in the first instance I would set y to be smallish, like say 1:100 and see how long it takes
extract( r , y = 1:ncell(r) , buffer = 3000 , fun = sum )
```

Now, the `raster` package does have some parallelism built in, which with access to a large, large, *large* multi-core machine could speed up your operation a bit by running...

```
beginCluster()
extract( r , y = 1:ncell(r) , buffer = 3000 , fun = sum )
endCluster()
```

Don't forget to assign the output of `extract` to a variable.

Comment: @llik: try it on a small example, then a slightly larger example, then a bit bigger example and then have a guess how long it will take to do the whole thing. Plan a celebration for when it finishes.

Comment: SimonO101, Spacedman & Carl: thanks for your suggestions. First a little clarification: my raster consists of the population density over an entire country. So the raster is not a rectangle full of data but consists of many cell with NoData or 0 value (e.g. over the sea or across the border). So in fact I want to run the calculation only on cells with data.

Comment: @Ilik So only on cell with values `> 0`?

Comment: I tried SimonO101's solution with extract, but I get an error message saying:
Error in .cellValues(x, y, ...) : 
  unused argument(s) (buffer = 3000, fun = "sum", na.rm = TRUE)

I noticed that my raster has values of -1.401298e-45 (is this -Ifn?), so I tried to do the same only for cells that have data, but got the same error:
> Pden2007[600102000:600102003]
[1] 77.98655 77.98655 77.98655 77.98655
> test = extract( Pden2007 , y = 600102000:600102010 , buffer = 3000 , fun = 'sum' ,na.rm=TRUE)
Error in .cellValues(x, y, ...) : 
  unused argument(s) (buffer = 3000, fun = "sum", na.rm = TRUE)

Comment: @SimonO101: no, I need to run the calculation also on cells = 0, because at a radius of 3000m there will probably be values to sum